# How do I integrate Oracle container registry with Azure DevOps?

Tags: docker, azure-devops, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am having trouble creating a connection between Azure DevOps and Oracle Container Registry.

Has anyone experience how I get the fields requested by azure devops in oracle cloud?

The requested fields are:

Docker registry

Docker id

Docker password

[Docker Service Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpzf7.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-docreg) from Azure DevOps Service:

```
Docker Registry  Required.   The URL of the Docker registry.
Docker ID        Required.   The identifier of the Docker account user.
Password         Required.   The password for the account user identified above.
Email            Optional.   An email address to receive notifications.
```

And here's one document from Oracle Cloud: [Managing Docker Registry Definitions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/iaas-classic/container-cloud/contu/managing-your-docker-environment-oracle-container-cloud-service.html#GUID-D50E90E1-5AD3-43AC-8750-9BBF23AD80C6)
.

In my opinion(`I don't purchase the Oracle account and can't test it for you :-(`), you should enter your Docker Registry in Oracle for `Docker Registry` in Service Connection, and User Name for `Docker ID`, your password in Oracle for Password, Your email in Oracle page for `Email` in service connection.

Check the relationship between these two pages:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are the inputs to the requested fields

> Docker Registry: < region-key>.ocir.io (See [here](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Registry/Concepts/registryprerequisites.htm#Availab) for region key information):
>
> Docker ID: < tenancy-namespace>/< username>
>   Password:  < User generated Auth Token>

More details about logging into OCIR can be [found here](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Registry/Tasks/registrypushingimagesusingthedockercli.htm).